# Iterate through pairs in a Python list and update the pairs during the iteration

Tags: python, list

Hi I am trying to make a code that iterates over pair in a list and updates the pair if condition fulfil

```
List=[A1,A2,A4,A5,E3,A3,E1,A7,E2,E3]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def pairwise(ListX):
"Pairs -> (A1,A2), (A2,A4), (A4, A5),(A5, E3),(E3, A3),(A3, E1), ..."
a, b = tee(ListX)
next(b, None)
return izip(a, b)

for a, b in pairwise(List):
  if a!= b and a == 'E':
   do something and switch positions
```

In this case, the pair (E3, A3) will be switched and the new order will be ( A3,E3) and then the new pair to iterate will be will be: (E3, E1) and not (A3, E1). The code I have so far make the action and switch the order of the list:

```
    List=[A1,A2,A4,A5,E3,A3,E1,A7,E2,E3] <--Initial
    List=[A1,A2,A4,A5,A3,E3,E1,A7,E2,E3]  <--Switched
```

However after the switch keep iterating on the pair (A3, E1).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because of how `itertools.tee` is implemented. Because it works on arbitrary iterators (not only sequences), it needs to store the values yielded by one of the iterators but not by the other.

You can work around this though, since you're actually calling your `pairwise` function on a list, which you can independently iterate over multiple times.

```
def pairwise(ListX):
    a = iter(ListX)
    b = iter(ListX)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Now, if you modify `ListX` while iterating over the pairs, the updates will always be seen.

Note that to do your modifications efficiently, you might want to use `enumerate` to get an index along with the pair values.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I worry about efficiency that is the reason I was using itertools.tee  how efficient ( time and memory) will be doing it this way?

Comment: If anything, my version of `pairwise` will be more efficient than using `tee`, since you don't need the overhead of a queue to hold the one saved value. Both versions will have the same `O(N)` time complexity (when iterating over N values) and both use only a constant amount of extra memory, but I suspect my version is going to be a bit faster and use slightly less memory. The limitation is that `ListX` does actually need to be a list, not an iterator.

Comment: I have another question,  in the case I want the  iterations to start over from the last pair of two A's, (A4, A5), or from the first pair, (A1,A2), after the switch; How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no reason to use pairwise function because it's return new object.

```
l = ['A1', 'A2', 'A4', 'A5', 'E3', 'A3', 'E1', 'A7', 'E2', 'E3']
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i] != l[i+1] and l[i][:1] == 'E':
        l[i], l[i+1] = l[i+1], l[i]
        break
print(l)
```

If you remove `break` next pair be ('E3', 'E1')

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I worry about efficiency how efficient ( time and memory) will be doing it this way?  I mean you are carrying and integer during the loop.

Comment: @user3671704 If you're want to change existing list the better way to work with list directly, because when you switching elements in pairwise iteration loop give no effect on `List` object. And also pairwise function require some portion of memory.